# Shift all objects in an SVG down and to the right by a given number of pixels

Tags: svg

Is there some kind of a wrapper object in SVG that I can use to shift all objects (lines, polygons, circles, text etc) down and to the right in a simple easy fashion? I realize now that I have not left enough space in the top left corner of my SVG definition.

Maybe there is a margin or padding element in SVG that I can use. Please note that I do not desire to wrap this inside HTML or use CSS trickery to achieve this, but ideally I would like to do this with pure SVG if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you can wrap all root elements of your SVG into [`<g>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g) element and apply (add) single [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform) to all its children through it:

```
<g transform="translate(10, 10)">
  <!-- content -->
</g>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either alter the [`viewBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox) attribute to reveal different portion of the infinite plane, i.e. changing e.g.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
```

to

```
<svg viewBox="-10 -10 110 110">
```

will bring extra 10 point rows and columns to top an left, effectively shifting content to bottom right (and shrinking it).